# How to test POST method with Postman and x-www-form-urlencoded Body?

Tags: post, pug, postman, webstorm

I'm at the final step of making my first JS Web App using Pug, where I need to test that it supports POST method, which takes in a string should return a JSON object with 2 key.value pairs that represent original string and its length.

I'm instructed to use Postman and x-www-form-urlencoded to test my App, but I don't know how to test the POST method using urlencoded body.

Can someone tell me what I should fill in for KEY and VALUE on Postman, under x-www-form-urlencoded?

```
//POST method in route file
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('ps3post', {string: req.body.string, stringLength: req.body.string.length});
});
```

```
block content
    h1 POST method, page rendered by PUG
    p= string
    p= stringLength
```

[image: My Postman Error Message Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out.. It seems that `KEY` needs to be type (`string` in my example), and `VALUE` needs to be what I want the actually value to be.

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: *"It seems that KEY needs to be type (string in my example)"* Highly doubt. Based on your screenshot `string`  is a **parameter name** .. so in your original code you would need to use something like `req.body.what` where `what` is the name of the parameter from your initial screenshot. But surely, if a parameter name meant to be `string` then it's correct (just a bit wrong wording where you have mentioned "type"). P.S. I'm not a JS person and not familiar with the JS framework used in your code  so could be wrong, although unlikely.